# Importing pytesseract

Tags: python, pip, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pytesser

I have trying to use pytesseract for OCR (extracting text from the image). I have successfully installed pytessearct by using the command -

```
pip install pytessearct
```

When I try to install it again, it clearly says -

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): 
pytesseract in ./site-packages
```

This means pytessearct is installed successfully. When i try to import this package in my iPython notebook using  -

```
import pytessearct
```

It throws an error -

```
ImportError: No module named pytesseract
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: Is this ./site-packages that came with python installation (or) a reference path from your project directory?

Comment: It is the one that comes with Python installation

Comment: can you create a environmental variable "PYTHONPATH"  and full path of site-packages as a value to the created variable (PYTHONPATH)

Comment: I created the variable as told by you. Is there any other change I need to do? Because the problem still exists.

Comment: Did you add full path of site-packages as value to that system variable that you created?

Comment: Yes I did. So in the bash file, I did - export PYTHONPATH = $(path of site-packages). Is that correct?

Comment: do "pip list" - is it listing pytesseract?

Comment: Yes it is listing pytesseract

Comment: IPython may be running in a different Python installation from the one pip is installing to. Check `sys.path` inside IPython to see the directories it will try to import from.

Answer (score 8):

To use Python-tesseract - requires python 2.5+ or python 3.x - first you have to install PIL and pytesseract packages through pip:

```
pip install Pillow
pip install pytesseract
```

Then you have to download and install the tesseract OCR:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr-alt/?source=typ_redirect

As far as I know it automatically adds it to your PATH variable.

Then use it like this way:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('Capture.PNG')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
print( pytesseract.image_to_string(img) )
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: instead of downloading the ocr: `sudo apt install tesseract-ocr`